# Red Hat linux - "turn off" encryption checking

Tags: linux, encryption, redhat

I have a Red Hat 6.5 Linux implementation that uses LUKS to encrypt the system and - for reasons that aren't relevant - I would like to "turn off" boot encryption checking for a period of time. It will be turned on again at some point so even if it is possible to remove the LUKS encryption entirely, that is not a solution I am interested in.

What I want is to auto-provide the LUKS password on boot so that it doesn't need to be entered manually - thus logically "turning off" encryption even though still actually enabled.

Now, while this is straightforward for secondary devices ie. by creating a key file, applying the key file to the encrypted devices and amending /etc/crypttab to reference the key file, one still has to enter at least one password on boot - because, if the primary device is LUKS encrypted, then it first has to be decrypted before /etc/crypttab is accessible.

There is a way I have seen of removing the requirement to enter the initial password which is:

1. create a key file
2. apply the key file to the encrypted device ie. enabling the key for the device to be decrypted
3. Copy the key file to a *removable not-encrypted device* (eg. a flash drive)
4. append rd.luks.key=*absolute path to key file* : *removable not-encrypted device*  to the booting kernel line in /boot/grub/grub.conf
5. On boot, make sure the *removable not-encrypted device* is inserted and can be referenced by the boot process.

This all looks good, except that I don't want a *removable not-encrypted device* involved. I simply want the server to boot as though it wasn't encrypted.

The only way I can see to achieve this is to replace *removable not-encrypted device* with *normal not-encrypted device*. In which case the boot process would read *normal not-encrypted device*, get the key and use it to decrypt the encrypted devices ...hey presto encryption is disabled.

The only device I can find on my system that fulfills the *normal not-encrypted device* criteria is /dev/sda1 ie. /boot , so I performed the above steps with step 3 and 4 as follows:

1. as above
2. as above
3. copy key file to /boot/keyfile.key
4. append rd.luks.key=/boot/keyfile.key:/dev/sda1
5. n/a

Unfortunately I can't seem to get this to work.

Red Hat boots and I don't get asked for a password (as expected), however towards the end of the boot process, it fails with "Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! ..."

This behaviour is identical whichever of the following I use:

- rd.luks.key=/boot/keyfile.key:/dev/sda1
- rd.luks.key=/keyfile.key:/dev/sda1
- rd.luks.key=/keyfile.key
- rd.luks.key=/*someKeyFileThatIknowDoesNotExist.key*:/dev/sda1

So my questions are as follows:

1. Is what I am trying to do possible
2. If yes, then...

   - where should I be putting the key file
   - what is the rd.luks.key value I should use to reference the key file

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: The silence is sadly deafening. Come on security guys ...someone must have some comments regarding this? It's an extremely powerful piece of functionality with many potential use cases - just one of which is enabling remote encrypted server reboot without the requirement for "on-site local hands to enter the password or insert the removable not-encrypted device holding the key file".

Comment: I give up: I have added the /src/keys/file to initramfs as follows `dracut --include /keys /src/keys /boot/initramfs-new.img`, appended `rd.luks.key=/keys/file:/dev/sda1` to the kernel line in /boot/grub/grub.conf and many variations thereof. Nothing works. And looking at dracut init.log, I get nothing back except repeated `No key found for /dev/sda2. Will try later.` ...and subsequent kernel panic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After much digging I have finally found the answer (which works on both CentOS 6.6 and 7). Thanks to the following 2 resources in particular:

- [Disabling LUKS encryption](http://atterer.org/linux-remove-disable-luks-encryption-password-on-disk-partition-crypttab-initrd)
- [RedHat Bug 751640 - dracut ignores crypttab keyfile](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=751640)

What I did is as follows (as root user):

```
# insert a password into my chosen password file
echo -n "anypassword" > /etc/mypasswdfile

# instruct the LUKS device to take the password from my password file
vi /etc/crypttab and replaced the 3rd parameter "none" with "/etc/mypasswdfile"

# add my password file as a valid key for the luks device
cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sda2 /etc/mypasswdfile

# configure dracut to add the following 2 items to the initramfs (so accessible at boot)
echo 'install_items="/etc/mypasswdfile /etc/crypttab"' > /etc/dracut.conf.d/99-mypwfile.conf

# instruct dracut to apply the configuration
dracut -f

# reboot the server
reboot
```

And that's it. The server reboots without requesting a password. (This can be disabled/enabled at will by removing/adding the keyfile from the LUKS device via the cryptsetup command)

Comment: FYI there is an official solution for that: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/256833

Comment: @akostadinov - thanks very much. On looking I see that sadly I don't have access to the solution so I am not able to see whether or not it provides an improvement over my answer above. If you are able to offer any further information I, and I'm sure others, would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: It's basically the same as what you have.

Comment: another FYI, a solution for using external key: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/boot/dracut/dracut.html#_crypto_luks_key_on_removable_device_support

Answer (score 0):

I never had a need for this, but can certainly relate to its usefulness.  So, your post prompted me to review how this could be done, and the only way I see is to get the unlocking scripts/details into initramfs.

This is a much easier process in debian based distros, because it is possible to inject scripts into initramfs via initramfs-tools .. dynamically at boot.  See [this](http://www.matthew.ath.cx/articles/cryptkey) and [this](http://forum.doozan.com/read.php?2,6039) and [this](http://madduck.net/docs/cryptdisk/)

RHEL based distros would require the use of dracut (in recovery mode) to rebuild initramfs.  So, I think you can solve this problem by rebuilding the initramfs and injecting your unlocking scripts in there .. that way we can be sure your root/boot device have been unlocked before the kernel needs to mount them.  This [Gentoo thread](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-429263-highlight-initramfs.html) suggests a way to get at and modify initramfs contents.  As to the best way to inject your unlock scripts in initramfs, I am not sure about that.

I will certainly have a go at this when I am less busy.  It does sound a rather useful thing to be able to setup.

Comment: Thanks Chux - here is what I would like to be able to do on an encrypted linux box:
1. log on
2. "logically" disable encryption for the reboot
3. reboot
4. re-enable encryption

This ability would allow comprehensive remote management of an encrypted server. (which is currently not possible for me)
Do you believe your answer above could cater for this scenario?

Comment: Apologies, I would like to enhance the wording of my comment above to read: 1. log on 2. disable password check on boot 3. reboot. 4. re-enable password check on boot (so that if the machine is subsequently rebooted the rebooter will be prompted for the password as normal)

Comment: From the various links I posted earlier, Debian users have been able to achieve similar things.  So, I think the things you want to do are certainly possible .. The challenge lies in initramfs, and I am not yet sure how best to handle RHEL initramfs to achieve this.  Will certainly give this a good go later in the week, when I am freer.

Comment: If you do get a chance to look at this I would greatly appreciate it as I simply cannot find a way of achieving this (see my latest comment above)